# Page cannot be null during converting a grid

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, radgrid

I have a rad Grid which i am trying to convert in to simple html but i am showing a error which i am not understanding to solve
Here is my code

```
private string getHTML(RadGrid gv)
    {
        string result;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter(sb);
        HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);


        htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Html);
        htmlwriter.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Body);
        gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
        htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
        htmlwriter.RenderEndTag();
        htmlwriter.Flush();
        result = stringwriter.ToString();

        htmlwriter.Close();
        stringwriter.Close();
        return result;

    }
```

The Error is here

> Page cannot be null. Please ensure that this operation is being performed in the context of an ASP.NET request.

and the error is on this line

```
gv.RenderControl(htmlwriter);
```

Please any one give me idea to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call RenderControl, you need to add the RadGrid-gv to the controls collection of something already in the page e.g. the form:

```
Page.Form.Controls.Add(gv);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Now this error is showing `Script control '' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
Parameter name: scriptControl`

Comment: Have you added <telerik:RadScriptManager> in your page?

Comment: Ya I have already added like this after form tag `<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
  <Scripts>
   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
  </Scripts>
 </telerik:RadScriptManager>`

Comment: Try registering your control with script manager programmatically.          ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
sm.RegisterScriptControl(yourControl);

Comment: `yourControl` which control would be this ? and where i have to make registration in page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22045/discussion-between-user1915635-and-amit-thakkar)

Comment: I have register control after rendering gv but now this error is showing `Script control '' is not a registered script control. Script controls must be registered using RegisterScriptControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors(). 
Parameter name: scriptControl